# How can I add page number on landscape A3 paper which I add with \includepdf?

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I add A3 landscape pdf in my LaTeX document with following code:

```
\eject \pdfpagewidth=29.7cm \pdfpageheight=42cm
\includepdf[width=2.6\textwidth,landscape,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},offset=95 -170]{sinkhole.pdf}
```

However, page number seems like:
[image]

How can fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the misplaced page number.

Changing the size of the page is not enough. In general you have to recalculate all dimensions specifying the page area, which is not an easy task if you want to do this on your own. Try to find a package/class which provides this functionality. One option are the KOMA-script classes. The following example uses `\areaset` and `\recalctypearea` from the KOMA-script classes:

````
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  DIV=12,
  headsepline,
  footsepline
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\lipsum

\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}%
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}

\includepdf[
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}}
]{tiger.pdf}

\lipsum

\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=portrait,DIV=12}
\recalctypearea

\lipsum

\end{document}
```
````